# Invisible input-label with item-floating-label and set input value

Tags: ionic-framework

In [this sample](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rarevd) I expected the Email label to be visible above the email input. It appears if I start to edit the input data.

Am I doing something wrong here?

```
<label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
  <span class="input-label">Email</span>
  <input type="email" value="me@example.com">
</label>
```

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I just ran into the same issue.

Comment: Nope, I think someone has to submit an issue to ionic regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

With ng-model in stead of value it will have the expected behaviour. So change your code to

```
<label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
  <span class="input-label">Email</span>
  <input type="email" ng-model="account.email">
</label>
```

and add something like the following in your controller

```
$scope.account = {
    email: 'me@example.com'
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem using AppGyver Supersonic.
I solved controlling the `has-input` class on my `input-label` using `ng-class`, like this:

```
<label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
  <span class="input-label" ng-class="{'has-input': username}">Choose a username</span>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Choose a username" ng-model="username">
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `item-floating-label` class animates the label as the user types in the input field. Refer documentation for more details.

http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#forms-floating-labels

For your requirement to always show the label above the input field, you have to use the `item-stacked-label`

http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#forms-stacked-labels

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't agree. `Item-stacked-label` is a separate type with different behavior. I want the control to work as `item-floating-label` but also support the case where there is already a value set. Please compare with [this](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-floating-labels) below "Light theme" there is a sample called "Normal with input text + label". That's what I expected it to look like.

Answer (score 0):

Set the placeholder with the same text as the label. In this case `placeholder="Email"`. 
The Floating item label works this way.. Until the field is filled, the label will not be visible, instead the placeholder will be visible. Just as you type in the field, the label will appear.The animation is sleek and nice. Just make sure the text is same.(case sensitive.)